# Translation Help

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

I'm unsure how to best translate the bolded part of the sentence:

"Deinde cum fideles & in fide perseverantes aut morientes objectum esse dicimus electionis & infideles objectum reprobationis, eos tantum intelligi posse ac debere statuimus, quibus gratia divina aut reipsa iam facta est, ut credere possent, **& iam credentes in fide perseverare ad finem usque**."

What I have is:

"Next, when we say that believers and those who persevere or die in faith are the object of election and that unbelievers are the object of reprobation, we hold that they only can and should be understood to whom God has either already in reality given divine grace that they might be able to believe, **and who now believing, to persevere in faith to the very end.**"

Should it be as I have it now, or "and who having already believed, persevere in faith to the very end?"

An explanation for your answer would be great!

Comment: I remember you posting this passage a couple years ago. From which work does it come?

Comment: It comes from the Acta Et Scripta Synodalia Dordracena Ministrorum Remonstrantium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you've basically got it. I think that *iam* means here "already", "still", or "till now", so that *ut credere possent, et iam credentes [possent] in fide perseverare ad finem usque* means "that they might believe, and [that] those already believing [might] persevere in the faith all the way to the end."